# How to send the value of select while onchange in django?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates

```
       <main>
           <section class="topbar">
            <select name="category" id="category" 
          onchange="location.href='{% url 'searchbycategory' this.value %}'">
               <option value="none">All category</option>
               <option value="book">Books</option>
              <option value="notes">Notes</option>
              <option value="fur">Furniture</option>
             <option value="draw">Drawing tools</option>
             <option value="others">Others</option>
          </select>
        </section>
```

is there something like this.value to send the current selected value

this is my path in url.py:
path('searchbycategory/str:category',views.searchbycategory,name="searchbycategory")

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your Django `{% url %}` creates the url when the template is rendered and won't dynamically change as `this.value` changes. What you will need to do is manually change the url in javascript when the select changes.